TypeScript: How to refactor a switch statement to a direct method call without type errors?
Types:
type CMYK = [number, number, number, number];
type HSV = [number, number, number];
type Color = {
    colorType: "cmyk";
    value: CMYK;
} | {
    colorType: "hsv";
    value: HSV;
}

declare const color: Color;
const convert = {
  cmyk: { hex: (value: CMYK) => value },
  hsv: { hex: (value: HSV) => value },
};
const { colorType, value } = color;
colorType;
// ^? const colorType: "cmyk" | "hsv"
value;
// ^? const value: CMYK | HSV

I have a switch case in my code like this, and it works:
switch (colorType) {
  case "cmyk": {
    convert[colorType].hex(value);
    break;
  }
  case "hsv": {
    convert[colorType].hex(value);
    break;
  }
}

The actual code has 10 more of these cases, and they all have the same code. I wanted to refactor the above to something like this:
convert[colorType].hex(value)

But then I have an error that:

Argument of type 'CMYK | HSV' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
The intersection 'CMYK & HSV' was reduced to 'never' because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type 'CMYK' is not assignable to type 'never'.

View in typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgsgTQNJQLxQNoDsCuBbAIwgCcAaKXQk8yosi-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-P-IA
Tried:
Creating a generic toHex function:
type ColorMap = {
  cmyk: CMYK;
  hsv: HSV;
}

function toHex<T extends keyof ColorMap>(
  colorType: T,
  value: ColorMap[T],
): void {
  convert[colorType].hex(value);
}

However I still get the same error:

Argument of type 'CMYK | HSV' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
The intersection 'CMYK & HSV' was reduced to 'never' because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type 'CMYK' is not assignable to type 'never'.


Your generic approach is the right basic idea, but TS needs the types to be written so that the generic operation is explicitly part of the type. The required refactoring is described in ms/TS#47109. If I do that I get this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?
